# Inertial precession of a rigid body

Tags: rotation, precession

Is inertial precession of a rigid body possible?

In other words, can [axis of rotation of a rigid body] rotate itself inertially and perpetually around the center of mass?

Assuming no torque, no gravity, no internal tensions / vortices etc.

Comment: Do you mean [precession](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precession). You have precession as one of your tags, so are you talking about something similar? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, as far as I know I'm talking about precession.

Comment: So does the link I provided help you, or do you need more? Or something else explained?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't get from the link if inertial precession motion is possible. Some other online sources seem to hint that it isn't, but I don't quite see why.

Comment: Edited: word 'precession' is now added to the question for clarity